# Minecraft setblock chest cannot use replace

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am aware that ordinarily in Minecraft one can use:

```
\setblock x y z minecraft:block0 0 replace minecraft:blockname1
```

to set a block with the ID name: `block0` on the coordinate, but only if the block which was before has ID name: `block1`; this does however not seem to be the case if the block I desire to set is chest (or other blocks which can contain things, such as for instance hoppers). If I type

```
\setblock x y z minecraft:chest
```

it works fine

```
\setblock x y z minecraft:chest 0 replace
```

works as well; however

```
\setblock x y z minecraft:chest 0 replace minecraft:block1
```

(of course I don't write `block1`, I instead use any real blockname)

fails with the error message:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.
```

I have (obviously) attempted this:

```
\setblock x y z minecraft:chest 0 {} replace minecraft:block1
```

Which does cause chest to be placed, but it does however **not** only do if the block that was there before had ID name: `block1`.

My question: Is there a way to use the setblock command to set a chest (or other item containing blocks) but only if it replaces a specific other block?

Comment: Dumb clarification question incoming: you are replacing `block1` with an actual block id in your implementation, right?

Comment: yes, (as i have just edited into the question) `block1` and `block0` are only placeholders for the actual ID names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/setblock` does not support replacing specific blocks. The `/fill` command does:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 block1 0 replace block2 0
```

However, if "block1" is a tile entity, then you **cannot** replace a specific block and must instead supply NBT data. See [this explanation](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-61864?focusedCommentId=175057&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-175057) by Searge:

> Replacing blocks with tile entities is not supported, this is due to a limitation in the parsing of commands. It may be changed in the future, but not until after 1.8.

A chest is a tile entity, meaning you cannot use this to replace a specific block with a chest.

---

As a work-around, you could detect the existence of the particular block first using `/testforblock`:

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:stone 0
```

And then use `/setblock` if that command succeeded:

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:chest
```